# How to select data in postgres with count and limit in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql

A PostgreSQL table with data in the format

the table name is tbl1
tbl1

```
id -- RCODE -- CCODE -- LDATA
1     123      50        p1
2     124      51        p2
3     126      50        p3
```

.......................
.........
.....
.

```
23     116      56        p3
24     126      50        p9
25     126      50        p3
26     136      56        p5
27     126      50        p3
28     146      52        p7
```

My problem is how to find the count of `CCODE =50` from last 7 records of the db having `RCODE =126`

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to generate an intermediate table `a` which contains the *last 7 records of the db having RCODE=126*. Then run `COUNT` over it `WHERE CCODE=50`. Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT CCODE
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE RCODE = 126
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7
) AS a
WHERE CCODE = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as total
from (
    select CCODE
    from tbl1
    where RCODE = 126
    order by id desc
    limit 7
    ) s
where CCODE = 50
```